# Magento 2 overriding a vendor xml file

Tags: magento2, overrides, xml

I want to override an xml file of an extension module into my custom module, how can I do it?

Comment: Which file you want to override?

Comment: @YDF , if the below solution works for you than you can mark this as Answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Impunkj it's algolia_search_handle_prevent_backend_rendering.xml file

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this in your custom Module:-

> Your_VendorName\Your_ModuleName\etc\di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
     <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select" type="Your_VendorName\Your_ModuleName\Model\Framework\View\Element\Html\Select" />
</config>
```

Comment: @YDF , if this solution works for you than you can mark this as Answer. Thanks.

Comment: **@xMageStore**, the solution you suggested doesn't work!